# Parameter as a result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, parameters

I am looking for a way to use a parameter as a result that can be plugged in to another select statement later down the line.

This is the `CTE` select statement that I am able to pull by manually changing all four of the dates listed to what I want

```
SELECT          CurrentYearEmp.PRCo,
            CurrentYearEmp.Employee,
            CASE
            WHEN CurrentYearEmp.PREndDate <> '2016-11-20'
                THEN '2016-11-20 00:00:00'
            WHEN CurrentYearEmp.PREndDate = '2016-11-20'
                THEN '2016-11-20 00:00:00'
            END AS 'ParameterPREndDate'
```

I am able to replace the first half of the `WHEN` statement with a parameter like this

```
SELECT          CurrentYearEmp.PRCo,
            CurrentYearEmp.Employee,
            CASE
            WHEN CurrentYearEmp.PREndDate <> @PREndDate
                THEN '2016-11-20 00:00:00'
            WHEN CurrentYearEmp.PREndDate = @PREndDate
                THEN '2016-11-20 00:00:00'
            END AS 'ParameterPREndDate'
```

But it will only produce the results I am looking for if the parameter is 2016-11-20. I want to be able to have `@PREndDate` as '2017-02-14' it will post 2017-02-14 as a result of the select statement.

Comment: You could write a table-valued function (TVF) that returns all of the values in a single row. The result can be used in a query, e.g with `JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Table Valued Function as HABO has already said.  Here is a simple example for one:

```
/*
--Create some dummy data in a db
CREATE TABLE SomeData
    (
        DataId  INT IDENTITY
    ,   Val         VARCHAR(8)
    , Dt            DATE
    )

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeData (Val, Dt) VALUES ('A', '2017-1-1'),('B', '2017-1-2'),('C', '2017-1-3'),('D', '2017-1-4'),('E', '2017-1-5')

--Create a table valued function
CREATE FUNCTION ReturnData (@StartDt DATE, @EndDt Date)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
Return
Select *
From SomeData
WHERE DT between @StartDt and @EndDt
*/

Select *
From ReturnData('1-1-2017', '1-3-2017')
```

The best thing IMHO about Table Functions is they can join to existing things as they are well formed objects in the database.  When you do Procedures and Dynamic SQL, you get a result set but that does not mean your code can be joined.  Table Functions can be cross applied to run off of cte's and they can be joined to other tables.  So essentially they are better for reuse but they have rules around them so you cannot do more advanced things like dynamic sql in them(as far as I know unless they changed it recently) and other things.  But if you want a reusable data set with rules governing input, that is pretty much exactly what they are made for.